# How to enter COMMAND SHIFT OPTION CONTROL characters with unicode?

Tags: unicode

How to enter the symbols for Macintosh Commands? I am looking already a long while for an answer. Here a minimal (not working) example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{lmodern} %% das ist der Schrifttyp, aber irgendwo ist dieser Font 
% immer noch definiert: Ah: hier line 53
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
% symbols: (cell)phone, email
\RequirePackage{marvosym} % hat verschiedene Symbole, auch Euro Zeichen
\usepackage{eurosym} 
% for gray color in header
\RequirePackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


    \begin{document}

    I need special characters in a text, to describe some Commands for Macintosh Users. 

    \begin{itemize}
      \item Enterkey: % \unichar{21b5}
      \item Optionkey: % \unichar{2325}
      \item Controllkey: % \unichar{2303}
      \item Commandkey: % \unichar{2318}
      \item Shiftkey: % \unichar{21e7}
    \end{itemize}

    Are the symbols of marvosym working, which I need too? \Mobilefone{}, \Letter{} - perhaps I would insert these two symbols with the Unicode Characters too?

    \end{document}
```

Would be very grateful for any hint!

marek

Comment: You probably need font with the correct glyphs. Probably, the "latin modern" font don't have the U+21B5 (and so on) glyph (but I'm not sure). Anyway, perhaps the package [`menukeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) can meet your requirement, without using `\unicode` command (see the section 4.5 of the documentation of this package).

Comment: Thank you quark67 - this was exactly I was looking for. In MacVim my minimal example is buggy, while running pdflatex